# Regular expression to find #ffcc00 and replace it with #fc0

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will find and replace certain patterns in a CSS file
E.g in the following string:

```
.boxOneHeading, .boxTwoHeading, .boxThreeHeading
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: MuseoSans500;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 273px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}
```

I'm using the following regex: #?[\s]*(.{1})\1{1}(.{1})\2{1}(.{1})\3{1}
This correctly finds:

```
#ffffff and
#ffcc00
```

But I'm looking to find only the #ffcc00 values and replace them with #fc0.

What do I add to the regex for this?

Regards,
Jacques

Comment: Ctrl+H, #ffcc00, Tab, #fc0, Enter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
var color = "#ffcc00";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(color, @"#(\w)\1(\w)\2(\w)\3", "#$1$2$3");
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

But I'm looking to find only the #ffcc00 values and replace them with #fc0

I'm a little thrown off by this, isn't that basically a find/replace at this point?

```
var replaced = css.Replace("#ffcc00", "#fc0");
```

Comment: Same here, it works, but it still finds #ffffff as my example did.

Comment: @Jacques Are you saying you want to to work for everything *except* #ffffff?

Comment: actually I just realised that this code of yours will work for both #ffffff and #ffcc00 at the same time. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
regex: ([0-9a-f])\1([0-9a-f])\2([0-9a-f])\3
replace: $1$2$3
```

[RegExr link](http://regexr.com?30tus)

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't prevent regex from finding #ffffff?